# macOS High Sierra 10.13.2; Terminal Tabs buggy

Tags: terminal, tabs, macos-high-sierra

I recently noticed something, rather annoying in the Terminal application, on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.2. I don't know if that is supposed to be a new feature or a bug, but it is not something I find useful or good.

I use the Terminal application rather often and I like to have one window (sometime two) and have a few tabs within a window.

But what is happening now when I set the tabs within my window, is that after a shut down; when opening the Terminal application again, all the tabs I have set are spread out each into a different window. **What can I do to avoid that and keep my tabs within the same window as I set them?**

Comment: I only notices I can't connect to any server anymore... ssh -i “.ssh/my.pem" user@server answers with a > command prompt... Crazy! Does yours work?

Comment: Indeed it also seems like there is a problem connecting with SSH. At least on one server I tried.

Comment: This has [also been asked on our sister site Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306572/terminal-window-shows-all-tabs-high-sierra), and has no answer there, either.